# Set command Time out for enterprise library 4.1 data access?

Tags: c#, vb.net, enterprise-library

I am trying to set command timeout for enterprise library 4.1 data access. I used below code for get command object from Database.

```
Dim dbCom as System.Data.Common.DBCommand
dbCom = dbCon.GetDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(sprocName, parameters)
dbCom.CommandTimeOut 'I dont find this property.
```

How to set CommandTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you posted command timeout is written as:

```
dbCom.CommandTimeOut
```

But it should be:

```
dbCom.CommandTimeout
```

If that does not help, you could set the timeout on the connection

[Open Microsoft.practices.EnterpriseLibrary database with just a connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401339/open-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-database-with-just-a-connection-string)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

[Sql CommandTimeout set for EnterpriseLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682215/sql-commandtimeout-set-for-enterpriselibrary)

[Enterprise Library 5.0 and Command Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030297/enterprise-library-5-0-and-command-timeout)